How to reset hints in a CP-SAT model?
Pretty much the title. I have a cp model for which I have already provided a hint when minimizing a given objective function. I now want to provide a new hint to minimize the model with respect to a different objective. Simply adding the hints to the model will result in a MODEL_INVALID status because the variables would then have two hints provided. Is it possible to somehow "reset" the hints provided so that new hints can be put in place? How to accomplish this?

You don't specify any specific interface and usage might be somewhat different, but looking into the python sources:
    def add_hint(self, var: IntVar, value: int) -> None:
        """Adds 'var == value' as a hint to the solver."""
        self.__model.solution_hint.vars.append(self.get_or_make_index(var))
        self.__model.solution_hint.values.append(value)

    def clear_hints(self):
        """Removes any solution hint from the model."""
        self.__model.ClearField("solution_hint")

This basically reflects ortools' native protobuf-based design as this is basically protobuf code-gen API interaction code.
This also means: even without any public API methods like clear_hints, you can remove hints by mutating the model-proto directly (if you have access to that model-proto; probably just by querying the field). In any language/interface (C++, Java, ...)!
cp_model.proto solution_hint
  // This message encodes a partial (or full) assignment of the variables of a CpModelProto.
  // The variable indices should be unique and valid variable indices.
  message PartialVariableAssignment {
    repeated int32 vars = 1;
    repeated int64 values = 2;
  }

  // Solution hint.
  //
  // If a feasible or almost-feasible solution to the problem is already known,
  // it may be helpful to pass it to the solver so that it can be used. The
  // solver will try to use this information to create its initial feasible
  // solution.
  //
  // Note that it may not always be faster to give a hint like this to the
  // solver. There is also no guarantee that the solver will use this hint or
  // try to return a solution "close" to this assignment in case of multiple
  // optimal solutions.
  PartialVariableAssignment solution_hint = 6;

Consider usage of this mode for checking / debugging too.
